# Using custom color picker dialog in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, propertygrid

In PropertyGrid [default color picker dialog](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14076298/ShareX/2013/10/mAGsVrcIPn.png) not allow to set alpha value of color.

I already made [my own color picker dialog](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14076298/ShareX/2013/10/7tECSPiRtP.png) and want to use it in PropertyGrid but not sure how to do it.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171840.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to use my custom color picker dialog in property grid and copying code of it here in case some need it too:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace HelpersLib
{
    public class MyColorEditor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            if (value.GetType() != typeof(RGBA))
            {
                return value;
            }

            IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

            if (svc != null)
            {
                using (DialogColor form = new DialogColor((RGBA)value))
                {
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        return form.NewColor.RGBA;
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
        {
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush((RGBA)e.Value))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangleProper(Pens.Black, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how it looks in property grid:

[image: screenshot1]

When i click button of it, it will open [custom color dialog](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14076298/ShareX/2013/11/WY1WMk8oak.png).

But still have one problem which i can't solve.
I can't use Color struct with this UITypeEditor, therefore created RGBA class.
When i use color struct, it look like this:

[image: screenshot2]

I will open another question for it i guess: [Custom ColorEditor does not work properly on Color struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886047/custom-coloreditor-does-not-work-properly-on-color-struct)

Answer (score 2):

To interact with `PropertyGrid`, you have to create your own "property class" ([as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302326.aspx)). You can customise different parts and thus there are multiple solutions for what you want. As a first approach to your problem, here you have a code for `propertyGrid1`:

```
Property curProperty = new Property();
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = curProperty;
```

Where `Property` is defined by:

```
public class Property
{
    private ColorDialog _dialog = new customColorDialogDialog();

    public ColorDialog dialog
    {
        get { return _dialog; }
        set { _dialog.ShowDialog(); }
    }
}
class customColorDialogDialog : ColorDialog
{

}
```

In this code, your color dialog (`customColorDialogDialog`) is triggered when clicking on the cell on the right hand side of the property name ("dialog").

Comment: I have like this image effects: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14076298/ShareX/2013/10/d4Z3Ue8VNH.png and i can't modify color class there because i'm using this class for saving too and it will look bad. So solution must be with attributes.

Comment: @Jaex I understand that you have created a custom ColorDialog (inheriting from ColorDialog as in my sample code) which takes the class you are referring in the picture as one of its properties, isn't it? As far as a ColorDialog-type class is defined you don't need to worry about anything else; just replace my customColorDialog : ColorDialog with your class.

Comment: @Jaex can you please update your question with the code defining your custom color dialog? In this way, I would be able to address your doubts clearer.

Comment: Here is my ColorPicker: https://code.google.com/p/sharex/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FHelpersLib%2FColors and here is where i'm using property grid: https://code.google.com/p/sharex/source/browse/trunk/ImageEffectsLib/ImageEffectsForm.cs and your solution won't work for me because i can't store color dialog property in my image effects class because it will be saved to my settings. Even i can ignore saving of these still it will look horrible to have 5 different dialog for each color in image effect class. I need to write more but have character limit so i can't explain with detail here.

Comment: @Jaex you were referring to a custom Color Dialog and thus I assumed it was built from the base ColorDialog Class. Adding a complex, custom control to the PropertyGrid is not so easy. You would have to perform a custom implementation (as shown in my link or in the one provided by Hans Passant above). The whole point of this answer, was giving you some starting hints, because of assuming that your control matched the expected conditions (ColorDialog). I hope that you have found something of this useful, but I will not edit my answer to account for your complex reality.