# Custom ColorEditor does not work properly on Color struct

Tags: c#, colors, propertygrid, uitypeeditor

I asked here how to use custom color dialog in property grid for Color struct:

[Using custom color picker dialog in PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445551/using-custom-color-picker-dialog-in-propertygrid)

From that link you can see code of MyColorEditor class if needed.
Now i can use custom color dialog but only if i use my own struct which is RGBA in that example.

If i use this custom type editor on color struct it looks like this in property grid:

[image: screenshot1]

But if i use RGBA struct which i created, it looks properly:

[image: screenshot2]

Problem happens because UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal not applying with GetEditStyle() i think.

Using Color struct can be better than using my custom color struct for me because then i can set DefaultValue for Color property without requiring to write my own type converter.

So my question is how to use custom editor on Color struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally figured out how to do it, ColorConverter was causing this problem so need to use my own ColorConverter like this:

```
public class MyColorConverter : ColorConverter
{
    public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Editor codes:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

namespace HelpersLib
{
    public class MyColorEditor : UITypeEditor
    {
        public override UITypeEditorEditStyle GetEditStyle(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return UITypeEditorEditStyle.Modal;
        }

        public override object EditValue(ITypeDescriptorContext context, IServiceProvider provider, object value)
        {
            if (value.GetType() != typeof(Color))
            {
                return value;
            }

            IWindowsFormsEditorService svc = (IWindowsFormsEditorService)provider.GetService(typeof(IWindowsFormsEditorService));

            if (svc != null)
            {
                Color color = (Color)value;

                using (DialogColor form = new DialogColor(color))
                {
                    if (svc.ShowDialog(form) == DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        return (Color)form.NewColor;
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

        public override bool GetPaintValueSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void PaintValue(PaintValueEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Color color = (Color)e.Value;

            if (color.A < 255)
            {
                using (Image checker = ImageHelpers.CreateCheckers(e.Bounds.Width / 2, e.Bounds.Height / 2, Color.LightGray, Color.White))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(checker, e.Bounds);
                }
            }

            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangleProper(Pens.Black, e.Bounds);
        }
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
    [DefaultValue(typeof(Color), "Black"),
    Editor(typeof(MyColorEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor)),
    TypeConverter(typeof(MyColorConverter))]
    public Color Color { get; set; }
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]